# HTML5 FormData sending empty objects via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have a basic script that is as follows:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('username', 'Bob');

    $.ajax({
     url: '/signup',
     type: 'post',
     data: fd,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (data) {
         console.log("Success: ", data);
     }
  });
});
```

When the request hits my server, I receive a req.body of  `{}` (empty) and there is nothing in req that points to data being sent. Whats going on here? How can I send data with FormData?

I wanted to test getting basic preset data from FormData and was unsuccessful. The values console logged in Chrome show an empty formData object, with only its constructor and the available 'append' method.

I am using jQuery v 2.1.4 and HTML5 and have confirmed that window.FormData is a valid object in Google Chrome.

My goal is to have a form that a user can enter an email, password, avatar, and a profile background image with the following form:

```
<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="msform">
  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Basic Information</li>
    <li>Profile Customization</li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Step One -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="title">Basic Information</h2>

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    Avatar Image <input type='file' id='avatarImage' accept="image/*" name='avatarImage'>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>

  <!-- Step Two -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="title">Profile Customization</h2>

    <select id="dropdown" name="profileColor">
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>

    Background Photo <input type='file' id='bgPhoto' accept="image/*" name='bgPhoto'> </div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Whats going on with FormData, it seems like a valid object, but I'm unable to append anything to it. I've looked, and it appears that others have seen an empty object in their console, but the data 'automagically(?)' appears on their server? My first code block is basically a copy for the docs and I'm having trouble with it. Would and CORS issues or CDN errors be the case? Something maybe not able to access as it should? No errors print in the log, only a blank object on my post request.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Express as the backend, [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) does not handle multipart/form-data, and you are referred to using [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) instead. You can integrate Express with `multiparty` like so :

```
var express = require('express');
var multiparty = require('multiparty');

var app = express();
var data = new multiparty.Form();

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    data.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if(err) throw err;

        Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(name) {
            console.log('got field named : ' + name + ', value : ' + fields[name]);
        });

        Object.keys(files).forEach(function(name) {
            console.log('got file named : ' + name);
        });
    });
});
```

Do include `event.preventDefault()` in your click event handler

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('username', 'Bob');

    ...
});
```

Comment: This was it! After adding multiparty, I was able to see the fields and values through your code. Side note for others, I did have to parse through the callback to see the values as req.body was still empty. The above code by Anugerah can be easily manipulated to populate a req.body object if needed. Really appreciate the tip! Thank you!

Comment: It's my first time encountering multiparty too, so I'm sorry I can't give you more code, but I reckon I'll be using it with AJAX forms in the near future too. Btw, do include e.preventDefault() as @charlietfl mentioned. I've updated the answer too.

Comment: would appreciate it if you could accept my answer by clicking the green check mark on the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't preventing the default form submit event and neither are you catching a submit by keyboard if user hits `enter`.

Try:

```
$("#msform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('username', 'Bob');

    $.ajax({
     url: '/signup',
     type: 'post',
     data: fd,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (data) {
         console.log("Success: ", data);
     }
  });
});
```

If you aren't sending files I would suggest using the simpler approach of removing the `processData` and `contentType` options and using `$(this).serialize()` for the `data` value

Comment: Hey thanks @charlietfl
I tried your above code with, with the included e.preventDefault(); statement. I previously had in my code a 'return 400;' but forgot it for this question. Any difference? Unfortunately I'm not seeing any behavior change -- req.body is still undefined in my server logs, and in browser console the FormData is still an empty object.

Comment: My guess is you are missing something in server..is it node? Do you have proper modules required?

Comment: I was missing something in the server -- a module 'multiparty'.  body-parser does not handle multipart/form-data, as I just learned. Thank you for your help!